# Exceeded maximum execution time during Import of CSV

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import-from-csv

I followed Google's [Interacting With Your Docs List tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial?hl=en) on how to write a script on importing CSV files. After a lot of help I got it to work. However when I try to copy it, or modify it in any way, it times out with the error message:

> Exceeded maximum execution time.

...and doesn't run. Why would this be happening?

This is the `importFromCSV()` function from the tutorial:

```
function importFromCSV() {
  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the file in your Docs List to import (e.g. myFile.csv):");

 var files = DocsList.getFiles();
  var csvFile = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getName() == fileName) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();
      break;
    }
  }
  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message of this "*times out*" and what do you mean by "*I try to copy it or modify it in anyway*"?

Comment: I get the error message: Exceeded maximum execution time. I got the script to work with 2 csv files i need it to work with over 200 unique pairs of csv files. if i change the file names the script ceases working.

Comment: You definitely give too few information to allow anybody to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: what do you need and i will happily provide it ... I am sorry i am very new to all this

Comment: for example : is the CSV that times out bigger that the other ? does it show result when timing out ? how many items is there in this csv file ? have you tried [this other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273268/script-import-local-csv-in-google-spreadsheet) ? (answer from Safa Alai)

Answer (score 2):

The CSV import example does a `CSVToArray` call for every row. That's slow.

Check out the advice in the [Best Practices Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices). The first piece of guidance is to reduce calls to other services; change the example to update all rows of an array, and then call `var arrData = [[]]` just once, and you will vastly improve the performance.

Replace this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
  sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
}
```

With this:

```
sheet.clear();

var numRows = csvData.length;
var numCols = csvData[0].length; // assume all rows are same width

// Make a single call to spreadsheet API to write values to sheet.
sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numCols).setValues( csvData );
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

I also found that I needed to change a couple of lines in `var arrData = new Array()`, instead of declaring the arrays like this: `setValues()`, I used this: `setValues`. It shouldn't matter (in JavaScript), but it did (in Google Apps Script).