# Importing csv to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to import a csv file in Google spreadsheet, from where the records have to push to Cloud SQL.
I have following question:

1. Google Spreadsheet limit is "Number of cells: 400,000" . My csv may have data larger than the limit.What could be the alternate to load the complete csv data to spreadsheet?
2. I get Exceeded Maximum Execution time error when trying to import CSV to  Google spreadsheet(referred the tutorial provided by Google).How the code provided can be improved to avoid the error.

Comment: It would  be helpful to see code you are referencing.

Comment: I'm assuming he's referring to this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section2).

Comment: I referred to the code given at : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section2

Comment: Re:2 can you add some logging to figure out where the slow section of code is and post back. Re:1 store the data in more than one spreadsheet is the only option that springs to mind.

Comment: Regarding part 1, an alternative is to bypass writing to a spreadsheet, and push your csv directly to your SQL server. Part 2 is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691051/google-apps-script-works-but-times-out. (You probably knew that, since you added a comment-as-an-answer there.) I've added a code snippet to the answer there.

Comment: Load it into multiple spreadsheets and deal with each spreadsheet individually

Comment: The current cell limit is 2 million cells.