# Google Script reading from a dynamic Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Script that reads from a Google Sheet. The only content of the Google Sheet is an `importData()` function that imports a CSV file. Will the `importData()` function in the Google Sheet be called every time the Google Script accesses the data in the Google Sheet? Or does the `importData()` function only get called when the Google Sheet is opened manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`importData()` is a formula, that is evaluated and reevaulated when a user opens the spreadsheet and when other cells that are referenced by the formula change.

So, this means the output of the formula is not available for Apps Scripts. 
However, using Apps Script you can easily write the code to do what the formula does. 
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273268/script-import-local-csv-in-google-spreadsheet/14638174#14638174) for how to parse CSV data

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping I wouldn't need to go down the parsing CSV road, but it is not a big deal. Thanks again.