# Google App Script to imitate File - Import csv file into a sheet using a custom menu item

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, file-upload, import-csv, file-import

How do I write a script that can let me select and upload a CSV file from local drive in a Google Spreadsheet when clicking on a custom menu ? (I want to replicate via script the File-->Import command but in a new menu being rendered onOpen).

There's a similar question here, but the answer uses a method that is now deprecated.
[Script import local CSV in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273268/script-import-local-csv-in-google-spreadsheet)

Deprecated answer

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload CSV to Sheet");
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Start Upload'));
  var form = app.createFormPanel();
  form.add(formContent);
  app.add(form);
//  return app;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);// show app 
}

function doPost(e) {
  // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;

  // parse the data to fill values, a two dimensional array of rows
  // Assuming newlines separate rows and commas separate columns, then:
  var values = []
  var rows = fileBlob.contents.split('\n');
  for(var r=0, max_r=rows.length; r<max_r; ++r)
    values.push( rows[r].split(',') );  // rows must have the same number of columns

  // Using active sheet here, but you can pull up a sheet in several other ways as well
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
                .getRange( 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length )
                .setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to upload a CSV data to the active sheet by executing the script from the custom menu of Google Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

##### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor as a script.

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("sample").addItem("import CSV", "importCsv").addToUi();
}

function importCsv(e){
  if (!e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"), "sample");
    return;
  }
  const csv = Utilities.parseCsv(Utilities.newBlob(...e).getDataAsString());
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
}
```

##### HTML and Javascript side: `index.html`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor as a HTML.

```js
<form><input type="file" name="file" onchange="importCsv(this.parentNode)" accept=".csv,text/csv"></form>
<script>
function importCsv(e) {
  const file = e.file.files[0];
  const f = new FileReader();
  f.onload = d => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).importCsv([[...new Int8Array(d.target.result)], file.type, file.name]);
  f.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
</script>
```

#### Testing:

When you test the above script, please run `onOpen` or reopen Spreadsheet. By this, you can see the custom menu. When you select "import CSV" from the custom menu, a dialog is opened. When you select a CSV file from your local PC, the CSV data is imported to the active sheet.

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Custom Menus in Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

Comment: Hello @Tanaike thank you for your support, you get the idea totally, I tried your script but the modal doesn't seem to have an option to proceed after selecting the csv file. Is there anything I might be missing?

Comment: EDIT: I just saw that after a while of just selecting the file and not closing the sample modal, the data is imported and the csv is imported by the script as intended, however, it would be great if there was  a way to show an upload button or some kind of proceeding alert of some sort after the file is uploaded?

Comment: @CloneItMrShiva Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new request of `however, it would be great if there was a way to show an upload button or some kind of proceeding alert of some sort after the file is uploaded?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Unfortunately, your this new request cannot be also seen in your question. I apologize I cannot find this in your question.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I'm sorry I did not explain myself correctly.

With your script the following happens.
1. You click on a custom menu Import CSV file item
2. A popup window named sample appears
3. A load file button shows in the popup
4. You select a csv file
5. Apperently nothing is happening
6. CSV is imported correctly to sheet and popup closes

I wanted to know if there is a way to improve point #5, it could be showing a loading text after file is selected or an upload button to confirm that the csv is chosen. I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: @CloneItMrShiva Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your new question. But I would like to support you. So can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: don't apologize, I can post it as a new question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303500/google-sheets-import-csv-popup

Comment: @CloneItMrShiva Thank you for your response. From your new question, I thought that I understood it. So I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Late to this party, but needed similar functionality. In the comments of the accepted solution OP is asking for the ability to display some form of feedback that processing is happening. I've made a small modification to HTML content to allow for this. This is a dead simple example so modify as required but it addresses OP's ask in the comments:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="importCsv(this.parentNode)" accept=".csv,text/csv">
</form>
<p id="progress" style="display:none;">
  <label for="upload" style="font-family: sans-serif;">Uploadling...</label>
  <progress id="upload"></progress>
</p>
<script>
  function importCsv(e) {
    document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "block";
    const file = e.file.files[0];
    const f = new FileReader();
    f.onload = d => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).importCsv([[...new Int8Array(d.target.result)], file.type, file.name]);
    f.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uploading it from local, it would be simpler to upload it from Google Drive.

Check-out the below code:

```js
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("file.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TEST').activate();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

This copies the data from "file.csv" in your Google Drive to the Sheet named "TEST" in your Spreadsheet.

Comment: I want to be able to upload and select the file, typing the file name in order to open it would not do the job. I want to have the closest experience as choosing file - import from Google Sheets menu.