# Not solved but I found out that the issue is not about the quoted code - Google Sheets Apps Script function does not work except for the owner account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my second question about the same thing but I believe I over-complicated things for the [first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76049061) and I'll be more clear about the issue now. I'm working as a e-commerce consultant and I have a spreadsheet that I use for getting shipping informations from each of my customers.

Since they use some common marketplaces and can get a CSV file containing order and shipping informations, I tried to give them a way to easily import their order informations into this sheet.

I started with Tanaike's code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71246111/18648301) and following the comments I ended up using [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71303794/18648301).

The issue I have is this: When I use the account which is the owner of the spreadsheet, the Html dialog allows me to choose a CSV file and then importCsv function runs. I mean the import is complete. When I shared this to my customer, he said he waited on the dialog screen about 15 minutes before closing it and the CSV was never imported. I then create a test account and got the same result with my customer.

I thought that the simple onEdit trigger might be the issue and I created an installable trigger so that the function will run as the owner. There were protected cells on my first try but I remove the protection on all the sheets and cells this function may interact. I also tried on different browsers to see if it has any effect. Since I have no idea what might be the issue, I just record my screen trying the same thing with the owner and test account.

Here is the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hLw5C5fz9iNRM9UQeQrFKO468_Zp1fyZ/view?usp=share_link) of what I did. I had only 5 mins of video recording time so I tried to did my best. I hope it helps someone figure out why this might be happen.

Below are all the related codes for my project. Thanks!

CreateTrigger.gs

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEditScript')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

Main.gs

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu("importCSV")
        .addItem("importCSV", "importCSV")
        .addToUi();
}

function importCSV(e) {
  if (!e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"), "Choose CSV");
    return;
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('csv read will start');
  const csv = Utilities.parseCsv(Utilities.newBlob(...e).getDataAsString());
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('csv read successful');
  UserImportWizardSheet.getRange('A2:K').clearContent();
  insertCSV(csv);
}


function insertCSV(csv) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('insert csv started');
  MasterCsvSheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
  var CsvRange = MasterCsvSheet.getRange(1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length);
  CsvRange.setValues(csv);
}
```

onEditScript.gs

```
function onEditScript(e) {

  var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  var value = e.value;
  var a1notation = e.range.getA1Notation();
  
  if (sheetName == 'WelcomeScreen') {

    if (a1notation == 'B2') {
      ...
    }

    if (a1notation == 'B4') {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B4').setValue(false);
      importCSV();
    }

    if (a1notation == 'B6') {
      ...
    }

  }
}
```

index.html

```
<form>
  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="importCSV(this.parentNode)" accept=".csv,text/csv">
  <div id="progress">Waiting</div>
</form>
<script>
  function importCSV(e) {
  const div = document.getElementById("progress");
  div.innerHTML = "Please wait while we process your file...";
  const file = e.file.files[0];
  const f = new FileReader();
  f.onload = d => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).importCSV([[...new Int8Array(d.target.result)], file.type, file.name]);
  f.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
</script>
```

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your script, I think that `UserImportWizardSheet` and `MasterCsvSheet` are not declared. Is this related to your current issue?

Comment: They are declared in another place in the project globally so I never got an error about them. I now see that the issue is mostly related with protected cells and I'm trying to find a workaround about that. The code works well, thanks for that. And I'm glad you take your time to comment on this. I'll update the post as needed. If you have some time I'll be glad to ask you a couple of small things privately. I'll create a new post whenever I believe it'll help other people.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `They are declared in another place in the project globally so I never got an error about them.`, I couldn't notice this from your question. I apologize for this. And, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your situation. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: When creating the trigger you use `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID');` but your `onEdit` script uses a simple `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` - why do you use `openById` when creating the trigger? Who is the owner of the Spreadsheet, and what are the edit rights of the users?

Comment: `but I found out that the issue is not about the quoted code` Would you please explain this. Are you planning to leave this question intact, or edit the question (title and body), or delete the question and open a new question.

Comment: I'll delete this and open a new question once I take a note of what the comments asked and said about this. I have to improve the way I ask my questions I believe. Based on the comments I got here, the point of view I have slightly changed. I'll delete all the protection from the spreadsheet, start from scratch and then my question will be about how to add protection under the circumstances. Starting with a protection did not help me at all.