# Importing a local CSV file into Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, local-files

I'm creating shipping labels and pack some of my friends’ online orders. I tried to create a shared google spreadsheet for them to easily send me the address information. I recently added a checkbox to import a predefined CSV file with an onEdit() trigger, so that they could share the information easier than before. They sell on some ecommerce platforms so that they can export their order details as CSV and upload it into my sheet easily. Instead of a button, I use a checkbox cell value to trigger the onEdit function so that the script can edit cells even if the user triggering the function doesn't have edit permission on those cells. I'm not good at html concepts and I found an import from local computer script which writes the CSV into the sheet I specified.

(***Edit:** The code I used is from [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71241813/google-app-script-to-imitate-file-import-csv-file-into-a-sheet-using-a-custom) as pointed out in the comment. It was the starting point for me to think something like this. My issue persists since this code is not working on other computers who can access with edit permissions to my sheet. My test user can do the same thing to trigger a task on several computers, only able to complete the task on my computer but not the other 3 currently tried. All have Windows 10 OS, and Chrome as browser. Didn't asked for specific permissions, no error log.*

*Below is the remaining part of the main thread*)

I created the script file on my home computer with account A as owner, then add account B as a test account with edit permissions. There are protected cells and sheets editable for "only me" which is account A, and I tried writing the CSV contents into one of those protected sheets. Any user will have the same access with test account B, so I did my test using both account A and B. The script worked (and still works) as expected both with account A and B **on my computer**, i.e. when I clicked the checkbox it opened a dialog for me to choose a CSV, then parse it and add it to the desired sheet.

When I share the sheet with a real user, he can't passed the *uploading process*. When I checked the executions page, I see that it didn’t give me any errors but “completed” for all the onEdit entries. To understand if the issue is CSV related, I shared the CSV file I used for my user to test and get his CSV file to test it myself. I can upload his file from my computer without an issue, and he couldn’t upload mine which means the script doesn't work **on his computer**.

I logged in my test account from another computer I have and tried to trigger this script. I mean checked the box to see if it runs smoothly, I didn't passed the uploading process as well. So there is something working on my computer that other computers don't have. I don't know if it's related to the uploading script or some permissions that I gave before, but I don't recall giving any extra permissions for local file access, or if it’s really a thing. Plus, upload file button allows anyone who tried to choose a local file on the computer, so no access issue but somehow, the script can’t process the file and upload it.

I found a similar question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273268/script-import-local-csv-in-google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com) which was the first thing I tried, but as the comment below it says, I got an error saying UiApp function has been deprecated, so it didn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Here are the script and html file that I used. Both the function and html file are named "importCSV"

```
function importCSV(e){
  
  const MasterCsvFileSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("CsvSpreadsheetID").getSheetByName("ImportHereSheet");    
  
  if (!e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("importCSV"), "Choose CSV");
    return;
  }
  const csv = Utilities.parseCsv(Utilities.newBlob(...e).getDataAsString());
  
  MasterCsvFileSheet.getRange(MasterCsvFileSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);

  /*
   ****Some other code for calculations follows after this line****
  */
  
}
```

```
<form>
  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="importCSV(this.parentNode)" accept=".csv,text/csv">
  <div id="progress">Waiting</div>
</form>
<script>
function importCSV(e) {
  const div = document.getElementById("progress");
  div.innerHTML = "Uploading...";
  const file = e.file.files[0];
  const f = new FileReader();
  f.onload = d => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => {
    div.innerHTML = "Done";
    setTimeout(google.script.host.close, 1000);
  }).importCSV([[...new Int8Array(d.target.result)], file.type, file.name]);
  f.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The script that you referenced was published in 2012. A more recent example would be more appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google App Script to imitate File - Import csv file into a sheet using a custom menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71241813/google-app-script-to-imitate-file-import-csv-file-into-a-sheet-using-a-custom)

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks for your comment on this. The one in the link is the first thing I found which uses a deprecated function, so not working. The one I used is what you shared in your comment. My issue is mainly about the script working on my computer, but not on other computers for users with edit permissions. I want to understand why it works on my computer but not others', and how to solve that issue. I'll add a comment with a link to the original answer, maybe the one who wrote that code can help me about this. Thanks!

Comment: akivura, I don't understand the reason why you made changes to the script/html from [Google App Script to imitate File - Import csv file into a sheet using a custom menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71246111/1330560). It seems that you are trying to do something extra but what/why is NOT clear. Would you please explain your reason for not using the code from the referenced question and EXACTLY what you are trying to do.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303500/google-sheets-import-csv-popup](This) is the reason I'm using this code. It's a follow-up from the one you keep sharing. I'm following Tanaike EXACTLY with his updated answer since I try to create an interface for my users and this is better. But this has nothing to do with my question. My issue is the code doesn't work for anyone else except me. Do you have any idea why it works on my computer but not work on another computer even though I logged in with the same account? Is there anything you can think of that could cause this strange behavior?

Comment: I've run @Tanaike 's code with (2 users: one owner, one shared) and it works fine. Tanaike's interface works perfectly and either user can upload a local file. The reason I asked about what you are tying to do is because of `const MasterCsvFileSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("CsvSpreadsheetID").getSheetByName("ImportHereSheet");` plus changes you made to index.html. If you want more help, please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise this is unreproducible.

Comment: I want users to upload a CSV but don't allow them to edit the data so I use another spreadsheet which is editable by anyone. That spreadsheet has an onEdit trigger which puts the CSV data into this spreadsheet again. OnEdit allows me to run the code as myself so no edit permissions needed. MasterCsvFileSheet is just a temp stop for the CSV data. I believe I need to ask a couple of general questions before specifically work on this issue. My lack of knowledge about GAS, even HTML and JS prevents me being more clear about the issue. It's more than I could chew at this time. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `but don't allow them to edit the data` - this is pretty significant, a pity that it was mentioned earlier, and an interesting condition. There is a remarkable irony  - the user could quite easily edit the CSV file (that's out of your control), but you won't let them edit the spreadsheet? FWIW, I think you are still over-complicating things - the Tanaike solution just works.